# Can I change the key mapping for the debugger in IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, keymapping

I'm interested in changing the key mapping in IntelliJ for stepping over, stepping into etc from the default F7, F8... to something that will be a bit more convenient.  I've found that I can change a number of options in File --> Settings --> Keymap, but can't seem to find these debugger settings.  Help please!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure shortcuts for all the actions, use the filter box to search by action name or shortcut key filter dialog:

[image]

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite.  Great answer.